# Category theory, $(f\circ g)$ and $(g\circ f)$ are isomorphism, then ...

Tags: category-theory

> Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category $A,B\in\operatorname{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$ and $f:A\to B$ like $g: B\to A$ morphisms. If $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$ are isomorphisms, then $f$ and $g$ are isomorphisms.

I somehow have a hard time proofing this result. Everything I try seems to fail.

We know that $f\circ g$ is an isomorphism, so there is an inverse $(f\circ g)^{-1}$.

Now to proof that $f$ is an isomorphism, I have to find $f^{-1}$.

I tried this:

We have $(f\circ g)\circ (f\circ g)^{-1}=\operatorname{id}_B$. With 
associativity, we write:

$f\circ (g\circ (f\circ g)^{-1})=\operatorname{id}_B$

Now my guess is that $f^{-1}=g\circ (f\circ g)^{-1}$, and I have to show that

$(g\circ (f\circ g)^{-1})\circ f=\operatorname{id}_A$

But I fail to do so, and I doubt that this approach can succeed.

Can you tell me, if this approach could work? Then I would like to try it again.
Else I appreciate a small hint. I would like to solve it mostly on my own.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You found a right inverse, yes. Now first search for an arbitrary left inverse. That can be done exactly the way you found the right inverse by using  $g \circ f$. In that way you can still use your approach.

Now try to show that in general right and left inverses coincide (you can show that similarly). If you are having trouble with that, I will help you.

Comment: Thanks. I already tried that too, but also failed. I will first try again, and maybe write then an answer myself. I am thankful if you look over that then. :)

Comment: I think I got it. Do you mind taking a look? Thank you. Should I proof first that in categories we have this 'canceling property'?

Answer (score 2):

There is a more general fact: An monomorphism (epimorphism) which has section (retraction) is an isomorphism.
Indeed, if $f:a\rightarrow b$ is an monomorphism and $s:b\rightarrow a$ is such that $f\circ s=1_b$ then $$f\circ(s\circ f)=(f\circ s)\circ f=1_b\circ f=f=f\circ 1_a.$$ As $f$ is monomorphism it follows that $s\circ f=1_a$.

In your case $f$ is has a section and a retraction; in particular $f$ is a monomorphism (as it has a retraction) and has a section.

Answer (score 1):

As ThorWittich suggested:

We want to find the inverse of $f$.

Since $(f\circ g)\circ (f\circ g)^{-1}=\newcommand{\id}{\operatorname{id}}\id_B$, we have

$f\circ (g\circ (f\circ g)^{-1}=\id_B$ as a senseable choice of the inverse.

Similar:

$(g\circ f)^{-1}\circ(g\circ f)=\id_A$

$((g\circ f)^{-1}\circ g)\circ f=\id_A$

Now we want to verify $(g\circ f)^{-1}\circ g\stackrel{?}{=}g\circ (f\circ g)^{-1}$.

We have:

$g\circ (f\circ g)=(g\circ f)\circ g$

$\Leftrightarrow (g\circ f)^{-1}\circ g\circ (f\circ g)=g\circ (f\circ g)^{-1}\circ (f\circ g)$

$\Leftrightarrow (g\circ f)^{-1}\circ g\circ (f\circ g)=g\circ\id_B$

$\Leftrightarrow (g\circ f)^{-1}\circ g\circ \id_A= g\circ (f\circ g)^{-1}$

$\Leftrightarrow (g\circ f)^{-1}\circ g=g\circ (f\circ g)^{-1}$

We see that $g$ has an inverse similarly.

Comment: Seems good. Nice that you managed yourself! Maybe try to generalize that to arbitrary inverses as I also suggested for your problem. This gives you even more practice then.

Comment: @ThorWittich Oh, darn. Now I understand what you mean by that. I already know that an inverse has to be unique. The proof is easy (similar how you proof equality of neutral elements in groups). That is what I had in mind at first, but I was not sure if there can we left inverses, that are not right inverses. Or do you not mean it that way?

Comment: No, I am saying: Suppose you have Morphisms $f,g,h$ with $f \circ g = \text{id}_A$ And $g \circ h = \text{id}_B$, then $f = h$. The proof takes only one line and more general than your computation as it works for arbitrary left and right inverses. Thus it always suffices to find some right inverse and some left inverse as they must be equal.

Comment: Happens. Don't worry about it and just continue to work on your problems and you will improve :)